# enviar el valor de unos formularios tipo checkbox varios unidos con serialize enviarlos por ajax a otro documento php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, checkbox

hola estoy en un aprieto tengo varios formularios tipo `checkbox` donde el usuario selecciona los datos que desea en su reporte `pdf`, no puede ser uno solo ya que es por secciones entonces a todos los forms le doy un name igual y los mando con [], para con la funcion `serialize()` me mande los elementos de cada formulario algo asi

```
 <form id="formE">
    
    <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 5px;" name="check_list[]" value="procedures"><?php echo trans('messages.procedures'); ?>
                                        
   <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 5px;" name="check_list[]"  value="medicaments"><?php echo trans('messages.medicaments'); ?>

  <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 5px;" name="check_list[]"  value="prescriptions"><?php echo trans('messages.medicaments'); ?>
   </form>
```

asi con varios forms a los que pongo diferentes ids, ya en javascript para guardarlos en una `variable` hago esto dentro de la funcion enviar_formulario:

```
<script>
    function enviar_formulario() {
        document.getElementById("Btnimprimir").disabled = false;
        var formData = $("#formA, #formB, #formC, #formD,#formE").serialize();
       console.log(typeof(formData)); //sale que es tipo string
        $.ajax({
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'medical-histories/checkbox-pdf.php', // url donde enviaras los datos 
            beforeSend: function() {
                document.getElementById("Btnimprimir").disabled = false;
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('se envio la data');
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

el problema es que me sale error 505 en la consola y no envia la `variable` para poderla procesar en el otro documento `php` en la consola la variable si se imprime y la solicitud `ajax` sale esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
entonces no se si deba procesar los datos primero o que este mal en mi ajax adicional sale el error

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: MethodNotAllowedException
Message: (null)
```

Ya he intentado con `post` y `get` y el error es el mismo les agradezco si tienen una solución a mi problema.

Comment: Por el mensaje de error, es posible que en PHP estés enviando encabezados para definir los métodos por los que se puede acceder a la URL y no se incluyan POST y GET.

Comment: Ya intentaste con `JSON.stringify(formData)` y en tu backend con un `json_decode`

Comment: Te falta ser mas especifico con tu problema, quieres enviar solo el valor de un **check**? o todos los que se seleccionen?. Recuerda que al usar **checkbox** es para que la selección sea múltiple, si quieres enviar solo un valor creo que la mejor opcion serian **radio buttons**,  con los check se tiene que hacer una función de desmarcado al pulsar un ckeck diferente.